# WPF Window constructor crashes C++ application

Tags: wpf, c++-cli

I have a C++ application in which I'm trying to show a WPF form (named WSWindow), specifically one that inherits from the System.Windows.Window class so that I can get the window handle using the WindowInteropHelper class.

My problem is that whenever I make the call to the method below, the application crashes.

```
public IntPtr GetHWND()
{
    if (ivWindow == null)
    {
        ivWindow = new WSWindow();

        ivWindow.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.Manual;

        ivWindow.Show();
    }

    IntPtr handle = new WindowInteropHelper(ivWindow).Handle;

    return handle;                    
}
```

I believe the WSWindow constructor is causing the crash. On the C# side of things there's a WSService class that calls the WSWindow constructor, and if I put the WSWindow constructor in the WSService constructor, the C++ app crashes on calling the WSService constructor (something that works fine when the WSService constructor does not contain the WSWindow constructor). Also, in addition to calling the above method, I've tried the following in the C++ app:

```
WSWindow^ w = gcnew WSWindow();
```

and there are log lines immediately after this line that don't get written to the log file.

In the WSWindow contructor, there's a call to InitializeComponents, which is generated code in the WSWindow.g.cs file:

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
    public void InitializeComponent() {
        if (_contentLoaded) {
            return;
        }
        _contentLoaded = true;
        System.Uri resourceLocater = new System.Uri("/Project_Name;component/wswindow.xaml", System.UriKind.Relative);

        #line 1 "..\..\WSWindow.xaml"
        System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(this, resourceLocater);

        #line default
        #line hidden
    }
```

At first I thought maybe the call to LoadComponent was failing because the uri couldn't be resolved, but I added a log line in the WSWindow constructor before the call to InitializeComponent() which gets written when the WSWindow is created from a Windows Forms test app, but not when the WSWindow is created by a call from the C++ app, so it seems like nothing in the WSWindow constructor even gets executed, it just crashes right away.

There's no problem with references that I can tell; I've written a couple test methods, one that returns an int, one a simple custom Window object with width/height members and successfully called both from the C++ app.

I've also successfully retrieved the handle to the WSWindow when it is compiled as a WPF app and run before launching the C++ app, but I need to be able to create the WSWindow from a call within the C++ app.

I've spent days on this problem trying to figure out why the crash is occurring with no luck. I'm hoping someone that reads this knows something about WPF that could be causing this issue, or a known issue between C++/CLI and WPF controls. I'm totally out of ideas.

Additional info: When I start the C++ app and attach VS to the process, nothing shows up in the call stack (a separate problem for me to work on), but I noticed a couple exceptions that look like they might be related:

```
First-chance exception at 0x75a8b9bc (KernelBase.dll) in MM.EXE: Microsoft C++ exception: HRException at memory location 0x06e6b158..
First-chance exception at 0x75a8b9bc (KernelBase.dll) in MM.EXE: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x00000000..
First-chance exception at 0x75a8b9bc (KernelBase.dll) in MM.EXE: Microsoft C++ exception: HRException at memory location 0x06e6b608..
First-chance exception at 0x75a8b9bc (KernelBase.dll) in MM.EXE: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x00000000..
```

Comment: "It crashes" is not an appropriate problem description.  Document the exception you see in the debugger, post call stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was that I needed to mark the thread making the call to create/show the WPF Window with the [STAThread] attribute.